# WKWebView (OSX 10.10) won't load mobile google websites

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-agent, osx-yosemite, wkwebview

I'm using the new OSX 10.10 (beta 3) (and iOS 8) API WKWebView, and I can't seem to get it to load mobile websites, specifically [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com).

I have used an `NSMutableURLRequest` like so:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setValue:@"mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 7_0_2 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/7.0 mobile/11a501 safari/9537.53"
  forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Whenever I use this to load either of the above websites, I am navigated to the desktop version of the website.

Comment: This is happening for me as well. Accept, I am not sent to the desktop versions... the pages simply don't load for me.